# How to get Current Volume Level

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio, core-audio

I am working on 10.8

This is the code to get the current Volume of Speaker,

```
-(float)getVolume{

    float volume = 0.0;

    UInt32 thePropSize = sizeof(volume);

    AudioDeviceID devId = [self GetOutputAudioDevice];

    AudioObjectPropertyAddress thePropertyAddress = { kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar, kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput, kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster };


    if(AudioObjectHasProperty(devId, &thePropertyAddress)){
        AudioObjectGetPropertyData(devId, &thePropertyAddress, 0, NULL, &thePropSize, &volume);
    }else{
        printf(" doesn't have property to get the volume");
    }

    return volume;
}
```

Function **AudioObjectHasProperty** is Failing to get the Current Vol property , any idea what is going wrong,

This is the code to select the default output device,

```
-(AudioDeviceID)GetOutputAudioDevice{

    OSStatus err;
    AudioDeviceID device = 0;
    UInt32 size = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress address = {
        kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice,
        kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal,
        kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster
    };

    err = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject,
                                     &address,
                                     0,
                                     NULL,
                                     &size,
                                     &device);
    if (err)
    {
        NSLog(@"could not get default audio output device");
    }

    return device;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two options available. The first step is to determine what device you'd like and get its ID. Assuming the default output device, the code will look something like:

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress = { 
    kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice, 
    kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal, 
    kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster 
};

AudioDeviceID deviceID;
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(deviceID);
OSStatus result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &deviceID);

if(kAudioHardwareNoError != result)
    // Handle the error
Next, you can use the kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume property to get the device's virtual master volume:

AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress = { 
    kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume, 
    kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
    kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster 
};

if(!AudioHardwareServiceHasProperty(deviceID, &propertyAddress))
    // An error occurred

Float32 volume;
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(volume);
OSStatus result = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(deviceID, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &volume);

if(kAudioHardwareNoError != result)
    // An error occurred
Alternatively, you can use kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar to get the volume for a specific channel:

UInt32 channel = 1; // Channel 0  is master, if available
AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress = { 
    kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar, 
    kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
    channel 
};

if(!AudioObjectHasProperty(deviceID, &propertyAddress))
    // An error occurred

Float32 volume;
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(volume);
OSStatus result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceID, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &volume);

if(kAudioHardwareNoError != result)
    // An error occurred
```

The difference between the two is explained in Apple's docs:

kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume

A Float32 value that represents the value of the volume control. The range for this property’s value is 0.0 (silence) through 1.0 (full level). The effect of this property depends on the hardware device associated with the HAL audio object. If the device has a master volume control, this property controls it. If the device has individual channel volume controls, this property applies to those identified by the device's preferred multichannel layout, or the preferred stereo pair if the device is stereo only. This control maintains relative balance between the channels it affects.

So it can be tricky to define exactly what a device's volume is, especially for multichannel devices with non-standard channel maps. I hope that helps